# Sitecore Date and time

Tags: sitecore-client

I have a client with multiple content editors around the world, and they all use the Schedule Publishing feature, but, usually they are a little bit confused because of the Sitecore Date and Time, each content author works in a part of the planet, and they usually don´t remember the Sitecore Time(Server time), is there a way to get that without being an administrator, I'm thinking in a simple button to provide this information to them, but if Sitecore already provides this information it would be cool

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way would be to set the server time to be UTC as that is a nice easy timezone for people to remember. You can do this by setting the `ServerTimeZone` setting in the config:

```
  <!--  SERVER TIME ZONE
        This setting specifies the server time zone that is  used by the
        server to convert UTC time to local time, for example "GMT Standard Time".

        If blank, Sitecore uses the operating system time zone.
        Default value: "" (use the operating system time zone)
  -->
  <setting name="ServerTimeZone" value=""/>
```

That value needs to be a value Time Zone ID (List here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154758.aspx) - Patch that value to `UTC`.

Once it is set to `UTC`, your content editors can work with that timezone to calculate publish times etc...

Comment: So that would be a value of *1230*.